# How to select and upload file in ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

How to upload pdf file on server using `$cordovaFileTransfer` plugin.
I have a below input field

```
<input type="file"  onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)">
```

How to get `pathForFile` here ?

```
$cordovaFileTransfer.upload(url, pathForFile, options).then(function(result) {
 alert('Your image has been successfully uploaded');
},
function(erro)
{
alert("Failed uploading image on server")
});
```

Comment: check documentation http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/  they have mentioned about targetPath 'var targetPath = cordova.file.documentsDirectory + "testImage.png";'

Comment: But I dont have to uplaod "testImage.png" . User browse the file on the device and I want to get the path of selected file by user

Comment: "testImage.png" is the example in documentation and it means which image your are uploading. You can try ----  
var image = document.getElementById('tempImage');
            image.src = imageData;  

            var server = "http://yourdomain.com/upload.php",
                pathForFile = imageData; ---- Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534820/ionic-app-image-upload-from-camera-photo-library

Answer (score 0):

First add `cordova-plugin-file` plugin to your project. according to your targeting platform then you can decide where should save file before updating.

if you choose `cordova.file.externalRootDirectory` as file storage path then `pathForFile` will be

```
var pathForFile= cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + "UploadMe.pdf";
```